# How to get Categories of products In Observer?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I need to add a condition for my category in the observer, how can I call category?

Comment: @ShafeelSha ver : 1.9.2.3

Comment: Please check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try Something like this

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product'); 

$prodID = $product->getId();

$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prodID);

$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();

if($categoryIds[0]==4){
  // Do something
}else{
return;
}
```

Comment: I need to give condition for my specific category, like ID : 4, how can i call id 4 category in observer?

Comment: check my updaed answer

Comment: How can i check condition like, if cart contains only category Id =4 products

Answer (score 1):

> Get category and subcategory:

```
<?php 
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();
if (count($_categories) > 0){
    foreach($_categories as $_category){
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
        $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories();
        if (count($_subcategories) > 0){
            echo $_category->getName();
            echo $_category->getId();      
            foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory){
                 echo $_subcategory->getName();
                 echo $_subcategory->getId();
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

> To get only one category: (put category Id as we want)

```
<?php
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(4);
$subcategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
if (count($subcategories) > 0){
    echo $category->getName();
    foreach($subcategories as $subcategory){
        echo $subcategory->getName();
    }
}
?>
```

for more please [visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40217710/how-to-display-all-category-in-magento-1-9-1)

Comment: How can i use in the observer, my condition: if the selected category of products available in the cart no other products add to cart, and message like restricted products available in the cart you need to place a different order.

Comment: How to add more than one category id  in Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(4); @Shafeel Sha

Comment: please use  first method , you will get category collection

Comment: How can i assign my selected category id's

Comment: foreach($_categories as $_category){
   echo $_category->getId();

   }

Comment: My case, a restricted category of products not mingled with normal products, if the customer tries to add normal products assume cart has restricted category of products here trigger the observer not eligible to add and show a message like Cart has Special Product you can not add another and vice versa, my post -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/284297/57334  any help thanks.